# Автопрокрутка в слайдере

Tags: jquery, html, css

Всем привет!
Есть слайдер , слева название статьи, а справа картинка, и по соответствующей новости выдается нужная картинка.
Вот код отвечающий за описанные действия:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $(".leftBlock").hover(
        function(){
        $(".leftBlock").css('background-image','none');
        $(this).css('background','url("/img/arrow4.png")');
        $(this).css('background-repeat','repeat');
        $("#image").attr("src",$(this).attr("img_href"))
        },
        function(){
        $("#image").attr("src")
    }
);
});
```

Вопрос:  Как сделать "автопрокрутку" или "автошагание" ?

Comment: [Так же лень погуглить...][1]


  [1]: http://yeap.narod.ru/js/022.html

Comment: Да не я про слайдеры то знаю, этот то самописный )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
function slideNews(){
    var lb = $('.leftblock'); // новостные блоки
    var lba = $('.leftblock.arrowed'); // выделенный блок
    if(!lba.length) lb.eq(0).addClass('arrowed'); // если нет выделенных блоков - выделяем первый
    else{
        lb.eq((lb.index(lba) + 1) % lb.length).addClass('arrowed'); // выделяем следующий блок
        lba.removeClass('arrowed'); // с текущего убирем выделение 
    }
    $("#image").attr('src', lba.attr('img_href')); // показываем картинку

    setTimeout(slideNews, 5000); // 5 секунд - все по новой
}
slideNews(); // ПУСК!
```

А вообще, действительно, обычно проще погуглить.